# Blood takes from a suspect for testing

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

Consider the following hypothetical situation:

A person is arrested and blood is taken from him. In this hypothetical situation, we have:

1. The person who took the blood
2. The person who transported the blood to the laboratory
3. The person who checked the blood in at the laboratory
4. The person who processed the blood to produce the relevant findings

Does the prosecution have to call all four people as witnesses? What happens if one of the above people is not available to testify?

Comment: I expect the person who transported the blood would have a hard job verifying that it was taken from the suspect. The accompanyin paperwork should verify that the blood taken was the same sample that was processed in the lab. Otherwise a criminal trial would become tortuously pedantic. For example if transmitted by mail, who licked the stamp, who placed it in the box, who picked it up, who sorted it at the distribution office, who then delivered it, how much chance that any stage of that was tampered with...

Comment: @WeatherVane that's why such material is sent in tamper-evident packing, such as inside the cardboard box are plastic bags that are signed and stamled and unable to be opened without harming them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Chain of Custody](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK551677/#:%7E:text=Chain%20of%20Custody%20in%20Legal%20Drug%20Testing&text=The%20chain%20of%20custody%20forms%20should%20then%20be%20signed%20by,it%20in%20the%20patient%27s%20place.)

The onus is on the person who wants to introduce the evidence to demonstrate its relevance to the case.

A blood sample might be relevant to prove that there was alcohol or other substances in the accused body, and that might be relevant in, say, a drunk driving case. Blood test results from someone other than the accused are irrelevant, so the prosecution needs to establish that the test results *are* those of the accused. This is known as an evidentiary chain of custody.

This applies to all sorts of physical evidence. For example, you need to prove that:

- The bullet cases you want to introduce are the ones found at the scene,
- The CCTV video is an unaltered version of that recorded by the video camera at the time,
- The invoice is the invoice issued by the plaintiff,
- The autopsy report is of the post-mortem done on the victim.

> Does the prosecution have to call all four people as witnesses?

If the defence contests the chain of custody, yes.

Most of the time, the evidence is not contested - the prosecution says this is the blood test results of the accused, and the defence agrees. Done and done.

Where the evidence is contested, the judge will get submissions from both parties, perhaps including testimony or, at least, affidavits from the people involved and decide whether the blood test is admissible. This is a matter of law, so it is up to the judge, not the jury; the jury will not know anything about this. As such, it is appealable after or during the trial.

For example, if the blood test is excluded, the prosecution's case might collapse. If this is just a drunk driving case, this might just be the end; charges withdrawn; sorry for wasting everybody's time. If it's more significant, say a vital piece in a murder trial, the prosecution might seek immediate leave to appeal the judge's decision, perhaps other parts of the trial continue while this happens, or perhaps the whole thing is adjourned pending the appeal court's decision.

> What happens if one of the above people is not available to testify?

Subject to exceptions to hearsay evidence, the blood sample is inadmissible.

One of the hearsay exceptions is the inability of a witness to give evidence; they might be dead, for example. The judge can then consider whether the interests of justice are better served by admitting the evidence notwithstanding the contested chain of custody. Again, this decision is appealable and again, the jury will know nothing about it.

Comment: Consider the sample being *sealed and signed* by the person taking the sample, and the person doing the analysis checking the seal and signature. Would that maintain the chain?

Comment: @o.m. typically putting a sample in a sealed and signed container (and tamper evident transport box) excludes the need for the *transporting* and the *accepting* person to be deposited at all, and in praxis, the one performing the test is also the one that checks in the sample to the system (e.g. they receive the sealed transport container, open it and verify the contents into the system) - Only if the processing person puts to testimony that the bag was tampered with, the people in the transporting chain get relevant.